# Android Debug.startGC() at Bitmap.nativeCreate on samsung devices

Tags: android, bitmap, garbage-collection

I got strange behavior on my galaxy tab 10.1 (4.0.4) and SGS 3 (4.1.4)

DDMS profiler shows that Bitmap.nativeCreate extremely slow. And 97% of cpu time take `VMDebug.startGC()`

Another tablet Lenovo IconTab (4.1.1) works pretty well and profiler doesn't show any any abnormal GC execution.

So my application performance greatly differs on Lenovo and Samsung devices.

There is no any `Debug.start_anything_()` in my code.

I tried to make debug and release builds, run from Android Studio, and manually copy release apk to device. Reset devices to factory default. But it still extremely slow and profiler show .

Any ideas what could provoke `VMDebug.startGC()`?

Answer (score 0):

It may be late but this issue may turned out to be caused by too much object allocation. You can check [this article](http://tech.any.do/android-performance-optimization/) for reference.